# Is it possible to use regex conditionals in C? <regex.h> [Invalid preceding regular expression]

Tags: c, regex

Context:

I'm working on a school project where I need to create a calculator, which actually simulates a command prompt of a terminal (in C) to read just a few functions from the keyboard. So, I'm trying to use regex to avoid random and invalid inputs.

I'm working in the WSL on Windows (Debian) and so I'm including a library named **regex.h** on my source code. The problem brings up when I want to use a conditional on my regex. I know this because the previous attempts using other regular expressions work as expected. For example:

```c
#define RGXPROMPT "^[[:space:]]*((./fibonacci|./cuadratica|./sumaCuadratica|./sumatoria)(([[:space:]]+.*))*)|((fin)[[:space:]]*)"
```

...but, it was not enough. I want my regex to match the ***entire line*** if the following conditions are accomplished:

- The line only *can* start with **space** characters (' ','\t').
- The following word must be one of these (without quotes):

  - "./fibonacci"
  - "./cuadratica"
  - "./sumaCuadratica"
  - "./sumatoria"
  - "fin"
- If the previous word was not "fin", then accept...

  - *at least* one space and then any sequence of characters (if wanted), or
  - none.
- If the previous word actually was "fin", then only accept zero or more spaces.

Question:

After some bunch of time, I ended up with this, the *final regex*:

```c
#define RGXPROMPT "^[[:space:]]*(((./fibonacci|./cuadratica|./sumaCuadratica|./sumatoria)(?(?=[[:space:]]).*|$))|((fin)(?(?=[[:space:]])[[:space:]]*$|$)))"
```

I tested it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it worked. But, when I try to put it into my code, it shows up a compilation error of the regex.

```c
regex_t regex;
int return_value;

return_value = regcomp(&regex,RGXPROMPT,REG_EXTENDED);
    if(return_value){
        regerror(return_value, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        printf(" -> [ :'( ] Error compiling RegEx: %s.\n",msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }
```

This is showing up:

```
 -> [ :'( ] Error compiling RegEx: Invalid preceding regular expression.
```

I've made some research and I've discovered that there are different regex dialects, so I tried with this instead (it worked the same as the previous one).

```c
#define RGXPROMPT "^[[:space:]]*(((./fibonacci|./cuadratica|./sumaCuadratica|./sumatoria)((?=[[:space:]]).*|(?![[:space:]])$))|((fin)((?=[[:space:]])[[:space:]]*$|(?![[:space:]])$)))"
```

But it still doesn't work... I have no clear what's happening with my regex.

So, here are my questions:

- What's going on with the regex I wrote?
- In case there is NOT a possible way to use conditionals, are there other ways to do the same thing as these?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think you might need to escape the periods.

Comment: POSIX regex does not support conditionals, nor does it support lookarounds.

Comment: You shouldn't need something this complicated to accept zero or more spaces after fin: `(?(?=[[:space:]])[[:space:]]*$|$)`. Just do `[[:space:]]*` or whatever the syntax is. The dollar sign can also be shared with the other path; just put it as the last character in the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extended  POSIX regular expressions are designed so that they compile to *deterministic finite automata*; not all constructs can be supported easily, if at all in DFA, including lookahead. But you do not need lookahead for this. Just code the regex as branches. For clarity I use   to stand in for `[[:space:]]`:

```
"^ *((./fibonacci|./cuadratica|./sumaCuadratica|./sumatoria)( +.*)?|fin) *$"
```

so there is always optional space in the beginning or at the end, then two branches, either `fin` alone, or any of those 4 commands *optionally* followed by a group that has *at least* one space and then a sequence of any characters.